# how do i make my label text something depending if the value is negative or positive

Tags: c#, wpf

how do i make my label text something depending if is negative or positive value it gets from resultat7 in C#

```
 samenligninglabel.Content = "Det nye dæk er " + Environment.NewLine
     + resultat7.ToString() + "%" + text1 if negative otherwise text2 if positive
     + Environment.NewLine + "end det nuværende";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative and Positive numbers are, by definition, less than or greater than 0, respectively.

So, just check whether the value is greater than or less than zero:

```
isPositive = (resultat7 > 0);
```

Then you can use the ternary conditional operator or an if-statement to assign content to your label:

```
samenligninglabel.Content = isPositive ? "Positive" : "Negative"; // Change to required text.
```

Or:

```
if (isPositive)
{
    samenligninglabel.Content = "Positive";
}
else
{
    samenligninglabel.Content = "Negative";
}
```

Obviously, the first version is more compact and thus better.

Comment: i getting this error Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double' when using  resultat7 = (resultat7 > 0);

Comment: ok, so `resultat7` is of type `double`, see the updated answer.

Comment: yeah that worked with var but I could only make get it to work with place another label inside it are there any way to put it in 
`samenligninglabel.Content = "Det nye dæk er " + Environment.NewLine
     + resultat7.ToString() + "%" +  isPositive ? "Positive" : "Negative" + Environment.NewLine + "end det nuværende";`

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen You can instead try using a `TextBlock`

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen It should be possible. Try it. AFAIK, Label's support multiline strings

Answer (score 0):

If resultat7 is boolean variable you can use following code:

```
 resultat7 ? text2 : text1
```

Answer (score 0):

check if its greater or less than 0

`(resultat7 < 0) ? "negative text" : "positive text"`